# Deriving from a component and implementing IDisposable properly

Tags: c#, c#-2.0, components, idisposable

I have a Visual Studio 2008 C# .NET 2.0 CF project with an abstract class derived from Component. From that class, I derive several concrete classes (as in my example below).
But, when I go to exit my Form, though the Form's Dispose() member is called and components.Dispose() is called, my components are never disposed.

Can anybody suggest how I can fix this design?

```
public abstract class SomeDisposableComponentBase : Component
{
    private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components;

    protected SomeDisposableComponentBase()
    {
        Initializecomponent();
    }

    protected SomeDisposableComponentBase(IContainer container)
    {
        container.Add(this);
        Initializecomponent();
    }

    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
    }

    protected abstract void Foo();

    #region IDisposable Members
    bool disposed_;

    /// Warning 60 CA1063 : Microsoft.Design : Ensure that 'SomeDisposableComponentBase.Dispose()' is declared as public and sealed.*
    public void Dispose()
    {
        // never called
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        // never called
         if (!disposed_)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            disposed_ = true;
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
    #endregion    
}

public SomeDisposableComponent : SomeDisposableComponentBase
{
    public SomeDisposableComponent() : base()
    {
    }

    public SomeDisposableComponent(IContainer container) : base(container)
    {
    }

    protected override void Foo()
    {
        // Do something...
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        // never called
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}

public partial class my_form : Form
{
    private SomeDisposableComponentBase d_;

    public my_form()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        if (null == components)
            components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();

        d_ = new SomeDisposableComponent(components);
    }

    /// exit button clicked
    private void Exit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }

    /// from the my_form.designer.cs
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && (components != null))
        {
            // this function is executed as expected when the form is closed
            components.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

*I note that FX-Cop is giving me a hint here. But, if I try to declare that function as sealed, I get the error:

```
error CS0238: 'SomeDisposableComponentBase.Dispose()' cannot be sealed because it is not an override
```

Declaring that function an override leads to:

```
'SomeDisposableComponentBase.Dispose()': cannot override inherited member 'System.ComponentModel.Component.Dispose()' because it is not marked virtual, abstract, or override
```

Thanks,
PaulH

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`SomeDisposableComponentBase` should *override* [`Component.Dispose(Boolean)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d9yzd5cx.aspx).

You also need to delete the `SomeDisposableComponentBase.Dispose()` method (that takes no arguments), [because it hides the `Component.Dispose` implementation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691135%28VS.71%29.aspx), so they're treated as different methods, depending on how you declare your variables:

```
using (Component component = new SomeDisposableComponent()) {
    // Calls Component.Dispose upon exiting the using block
}

using (SomeDisposableComponentBase component = new SomeDisposableComponent()) {
    // Calls SomeDisposableComponentBase.Dispose upon existing the using block
}
```

Answer (score 5):

What is happening is that the compiler is interpreting the method Dispose on SomeDisposableComponentBase as

```
new public void Dispose() 
{ 
    // never called 
    Dispose(true); 
    GC.SuppressFinalize(this); 
}
```

which is not an override, it is giving a new semantics to an existing name inside you class hierarchy. So, actually you are creating a new Dispose method that is not the same as the Component.Dispose.

Check [Implementing Finalize and Dispose to Clean Up Unmanaged Resources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1yfkh5e.aspx) article for the official guidance on how to implement IDisposable.Dispose method.

Comment: You are right, I'll remove the last part of my answer. Thanks.

Comment: I appreciate that link. I hadn't seen it before and it's very informative. Thanks.